# Selenium scripts are getting failed in Remote machine due to Resolution of Remote machine

Tags: selenium

My Selenium scripts are running fine in my local machine.
But when I'm trying to execute the same from remote machine.

All the test cases are getting failed due to Resolution of Remote machine(Desktop).

Could some one suggest please, How to over-come from that problem.

Comment: are you using co-ordinates in selenium scripts?

Comment: set zoom settings to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine with below steps.
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024,546)).

We need to add this step before launching Browser.